In strapi v4 I want to show a page after login without creating menu link or button for it
In Strapi version 4 Admin pannel , i am trying to create a plugin for 2fa for that i want to create a new page consisting of qr code. I am done with showing the page with function addMenuLink this creates the menu link.
Now i don't know how to show the page with url like /plugin/two-fa/qr-code after login without menu links such that admin user should not be able to see anyother page until the 2fa is enabled
